# Finding matching objects in two collections of date objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two collections of objects. I would like to know which date-objects in `dates` have a matching from-date in `ranges`.

It's only the day-part that is important, not hours/minutes.

I use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to compare days `moment(obj.date).isSame(otherObj.date, 'day')`.

Should I use chained filters to find the matching objects? Or some kind of loop in a loop? I'm sorry if this is a beginner question, but I'm kind of lost here.

```
dates = [
    {date: Mon Aug 29 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)},
    {date: Tue Aug 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)},
    {date: Wed Aug 31 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)}
    etc...
]

ranges = [
    {from: Tue Aug 30 2016 07:30:00 GMT+0200, to: Tue Aug 30 2016 08:30:00 GMT+0200},
    {from: Tue Aug 30 2016 09:30:00 GMT+0200, to: Tue Aug 30 2016 10:30:00 GMT+0200},
    {from: Wed Aug 31 2016 04:00:00 GMT+0200, to: Wed Aug 31 2016 05:00:00 GMT+0200}
    etc...
]
```

Comment: Yes,  `filter` + `some` should do. Try it!

Comment: Pretty sure that code won't work. It should be `dates = []` not `dates = {}`, right?

Comment: Of course, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working with ranges, therefore it not sufficient to just check both ends of a range to determine whether a date is in the range or not.

Since you've mentioned using Moment, you can check out a plugin called [moment-range](https://github.com/gf3/moment-range). With this, you would simply construct ranges array using `ranges`, and then match every date from `dates` using `.contains()` method provided by `moment-range`:

```
ranges = ranges.map((range) => moment.range(range.from, range.to));

dates.forEach((dateObj) => {
    dateObj.matchingRanges = ranges.filter((range) =>
        range.contains(dateObj.date)
    )
});
```

(with this code, you can access every matching range per date using `dates[index].matchingRanges`)

Comment: Thank you, but the comparing part I've understood (I'm even fine to only compare the `from` part). My problem is how to iterate through the collections.

Comment: My code snippet shows how to iterate and find all matching ranges. You can provide your own comparator in place of ``range.contains(dateObj.date)`` line (please note this uses [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), but it's not required - you could use regular anonymous functions as well).

Comment: @mdziekon: I guess you should just put in the comparator that the OP asked for in his question